# How to center div in the page? (Height & Width)?

Tags: css, html, position

silly question, but I can't find answer on it as all answers assume centering div in terms of width.

What I need is to center div in means of height and width so in a very very center of the page.

I tried this, but it just centers div in means of page width no height.

```
#myDiv {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   margin: auto;
}
```

So how can I get it in the VERY center of the page? )))

Comment: Is this OK for you: http://vidasp.net/CSS-centered-page.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper with ID `wrapper` around the `#myDiv` element, and apply this CSS code:

```
#wrapper{
    display: table;
}
#myDiv{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; /*Vertically centered*/
    text-align: center; /* Horizontally centered */
}
```

This code centers elements of any width/height.

Comment: it's not working in my case

Answer (score 3):

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -250px; /*(half of width)*/
margin-top: -250px;  /*(half of height)*/
```

that should work.

Comment: got there first, yep this should work. If width/height is auto, look for js alternative. Must also be noted, parent div should have a `position:relative`